# How can I generate a v2 signature for Amazon EC2 using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I am wondering if anyone has successfully generated an EC2 v2 signature for their API using php.  All examples/libraries I can find online are for v1 of the signature and that has been deprecated due to insecurities. An existing library that implements the signature generation would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

http://mierendo.com/software/aws_signed_query/

I believe that's V2

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1669) a PHP Library that supports V2. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I've written and have been using:

```
define("AWSKEY", "Your AWS Key");
define("AWSSECRET", "Your AWS Secret");
public function get($parameters, $host) {

    // Build out the variables
    $domain = "https://$host/";
    $parameters['AWSAccessKeyId'] = AWSKEY;
    $parameters['Timestamp'] = date('c');
    $parameters['Version'] = '2007-11-07';
    $parameters['SignatureMethod'] = 'HmacSHA256';
    $parameters['SignatureVersion'] = 2;

    // Write the signature
    $signature = "GET\n";
    $signature .= "$host\n";
    $signature .= "/\n";

    $sigparams = $parameters;

    ksort($sigparams);

    $first = true;
    foreach($sigparams as $key=>$param) {
        $signature .= (!$first ? '&' : '') . rawurlencode($key) . '=' . rawurlencode($param);
        $first = false;
    }
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $AWSKEY, true);
    $signature = base64_encode($signature);
    $parameters['Signature'] = $signature;

    $url = $domain . '?';
    $first = true;
    foreach($parameters as $key=>$param) {
        $url .= (!$first ? '&' : '') . rawurlencode($key) . '=' . rawurlencode($param);
        $first = false;
    }

    $ch = curl_init(trim($url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    return $output;

}
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
$params = array(
    'Action' => 'ListDomains'
);
$db->get($params, 'sdb.amazonaws.com');
```

This would perform a `ListDomains` query on SimpleDB. The function itself will return Amazon's output. For more complicated commands, (i.e.: PUT, POST, etc.) there aren't any major modifications that need to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Use constant AWSSECRET to hash the signature, NOT $AWSKEY (an unreferenced variable).